# DeepLabCut Installation issues: Directory Doesn't Exist

Tags: macos, installation, terminal, apple-m1

I install anaconda3 and miniconda as directed by the install guides, git clone and change directory as expected. When I run the following command line:

conda env create -f DEEPLABCUT_M1.yaml

It gives me the following error/output:
| /Users/(USER)/miniconda/envs/DEEPLABCUT_M1/bin/.nb_conda-post-link.sh: line 2: /Users/(USER)/miniconda/envs/DEEPLABCUT_M1/bin/jupyter-nbextension: No such file or directory
/Users/(USER)/miniconda/envs/DEEPLABCUT_M1/bin/.nb_conda-post-link.sh: line 3: /Users/(USER)/miniconda/envs/DEEPLABCUT_M1/bin/jupyter-serverextension: No such file or directory

done
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(730): An error occurred while installing package 'conda-forge::nb_conda-2.2.1-unix_6'.
Rolling back transaction: done

LinkError: post-link script failed for package conda-forge::nb_conda-2.2.1-unix_6
location of failed script: /Users/(USER)/miniconda/envs/DEEPLABCUT_M1/bin/.nb_conda-post-link.sh
==> script messages <==
/Users/(USER)/miniconda/envs/DEEPLABCUT_M1/bin/.nb_conda-post-link.sh: line 2: /Users/(USER)/miniconda/envs/DEEPLABCUT_M1/bin/jupyter-nbextension: No such file or directory
/Users/(USER)/miniconda/envs/DEEPLABCUT_M1/bin/.nb_conda-post-link.sh: line 3: /Users/(USER)/miniconda/envs/DEEPLABCUT_M1/bin/jupyter-serverextension: No such file or directory

and as a result, running python -m deeplabcut leads to: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3: No module named deeplabcut

I follow the instructions for my MAC M1 as laid out here:
https://deeplabcut.github.io/DeepLabCut/docs/installation.html

Trued to open the DeepLabCut GUI in terminal, which stated that no module names deeplabcut exists. I believe this stems from a seperate error when I try to create the environment and the .sh files cannot be found/directories missing. I already installed anaconda3 and miniconda to try and avoid dependency issues.